# SetDlgItemText fills edit field with junk

Tags: string, encoding, cdialog

In my CDialog derived class, in the `OnInitDialog()` method, I'm pre-filling edit fields with prior configuration loaded from pre-existing config.

```
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, LPCTSTR(data->project_file.c_str()));
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, LPCTSTR(data->remote_addr.c_str()));
```

`project_file` and `remote_addr` are both of type `std::string`. They are filled correctly, with strings containing the relevant filename and hostname (checked under debugger).

The dialog items, though, display `㩆慜瑩噜獩楳屭獁整屲浴㙰䌷⹃浴⹰瑩c췍췍췍췍췍췍﷽﷽翹` and `㤱⸲㘱⸸⸰㐷촀췍` respectively. When I enter the data into them, they can be properly read, and their data converted to std::string relatively painlessly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in my compilation LPCTSTR is 16 bit, std::string's 8-bit c_str() gets misinterpreted. It must be converted to wstring, and only c_str() of that sets the value correctly.

```
#include <locale>

void MyDialog::SetDlgItemStdString(UINT id, std::string entry)
{
#ifndef UNICODE
    SetDlgItemText(id, LPCTSTR(entry.c_str()));
#else
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> conv;
    std::wstring entry_wstring = conv.from_bytes(entry);
    SetDlgItemText(id, LPCTSTR(entry_wstring.c_str()));
#endif
}
```